# Error deploying WAR files

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

I created a dynamic web project in eclipse and then export it as war file. I successfully deployed the war file using tomcat manager. The problem is when i try to access it , tomcat gives me 404 error.

I don't have files such as index.html inside the web app.

Comment: check catalina.out for suspicious messages

Comment: IF you were answering this question, what kind of details would you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `web.xml` the `welcome-files` section, in that section you define the files used as main pages for your application, eclipse put them by default [index.html, index.jsp, ...], you could change that configuration to your welcome page or servlet url.